# Localisation tool for translators to capture text into - outputs files for Android, BB, iOS etc

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, localization

I'd like a tool to help with the language localisation across our apps. We support iOS, Android, Blackberry at the moment.

- We use a manual process, passing an Excel file to client and back again.
- We do not pass resource files because the client can break those quite easily.

When I get a translation then I have to make the required files for each platform. I have hacked together some code to make it a bit easier, but I'm sure there is a proper tool out there.

Here is an answer about a similar tool, but for Visual Studio and the MS tool-chain:

- [What would be the easiest way to generate new localized resource files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704115/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-generate-new-localized-resource-files?rq=1)

---

This process is slow, but common (see related, not duplicated, questions):

- [Parse strings from Excel file for translating an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891533/parse-strings-from-excel-file-for-translating-an-android-app)
- [Is there a tool for non-developers (translators!) to edit resource bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006550/is-there-a-tool-for-non-developers-translators-to-edit-resource-bundles)

Assume:

- I  know the format of the files required by the platforms
- apps are already written using resource files i.e. no hardcoded strings

---

The **ideal tool** would have the following features:

- Present intuitive layout for client to update the various languages
- Look similar to Excel i.e. table layout
- Web based
- Allow easy output of captured languages into iOS, Android, Blackberry resource files

I have no need for an automatic translation tool, and I know they exist at least on Android.

I know I can write my own, and may have to - but this is one of those where devs often feel they must reinvent an already perfected wheel...

Comment: We ended up writing our own web interface for this, based on Pootle, but Pootle doesn't support BlackBerry out-of-the-box, so some customization was required even then.

Comment: About reopening: I see many questions on this site (not closed) that ask about the right tools for a given development job. There are related questions that have not been answered, so the need is there for this type of question. Mobile devs have been sidelined in the L10N arena. ... (those are the reasons I asked - however will respect the mods of the site - thx)